# "The host is unknown to Read the Docs" while hosting local RTD server

Tags: read-the-docs

I'm trying to see whether I can host RTD privately (behind a VPN). I spun up an AWS EC2 instance and set it up using the Docker image and instructions [here](https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/development/standards.html). Everything worked fine, but when I go to `http://<internal_ip>` to test it I get a page with the message

> 404 - Invalid Host
>
> The host "" is unknown to Read the Docs
>
> If you control this domain and believe this is in error, please review our custom domain documentation. In the past, we allowed custom domains to point to us without configuring the domain in the Read the Docs dashboard and we attempted to intelligently guess the correct project based on DNS settings. Now, we believe that explicit is better than implicit. Below are some steps to help you get your domain working again:
>
> - Ensure you have a CNAME record pointing to readthedocs.io
> - Add your desired domain in the Read the Docs dashboard for your project (under Your Project >> Admin >> Domains)

It points me to [this page](https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/custom_domains.html), but it seems to me that those instructions assume I'm hosting my project on the public readthedocs.io site. Any ideas on how I can get this to work on my private server?